# Estimator for repeated sampling and fitting

Tags: estimation, sampling, unbiased-estimator, estimators

Say I have a Normal distribution $\mathcal{N_1}(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$. Now I will sample $N$ samples $X_1$ from this distribution, and use estimators for $\hat\mu_2$ and $\hat\sigma_2$ to fit a new distribution to my samples $X_1$. From this new distribution $\mathcal{N_2}(\hat\mu_2,\hat\sigma_2)$, I will sample again $N$ samples $X_2$, fit again with an estimator $\hat\mu_3$ and $\hat\sigma_3$ against $X_2$, and repeat the whole process ad infinitum.

Now, I want my estimators to be such, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[\hat\mu_n]=\mu_1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[\hat\sigma_n]=\sigma_1$.

I have a gut feeling that I don't just need the default unbiased estimators here, as $\sigma$ will do a random walk over positive values only and has a multiplicative relationship with previous $\sigma$'s. More specifically, $\mathbb{E}[\hat\sigma_2]=\sigma_1$, but I think that $\mathbb{E}[\hat\sigma_3]\neq\sigma_1$ as $\hat\sigma_2$ is a stochastic variable.

I don't know what keywords to look for. Does someone know what estimators I need to use for this?

Comment: Your notation is confusing because you use $\mu_n$ in ways that implies it is a parameter, an estimator, and a random variable.   Even guessing what you mean, I cannot pin down the question precisely, because it's unclear what information one is allowed to use for these estimators: would it be just the most recent sample, the recent sample plus the sequence of previous estimates, or even the cumulative sample?  Please edit this post to clarify what kinds of objects these really are.

Comment: Only the most recent samples are to be used. I am sorry if the notation is confusing, but I have no idea how to write this in a correct notation.

Comment: Your characterization of this as a random walk (in the upper half plane with coordinates $(\mu, \sigma^2)$) is insightful.  Since you use only recent samples, it is an (inhomogeneous) Markov chain, but that guarantees it can converge to at most a single value (if it converges at all), making it obvious no such estimator exists.  What you're doing sounds like a description of some statistical procedure.  This negative conclusion suggests it might be a little misguided: perhaps we could serve you better if you explained the statistical setting and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The idea is that many state of the art black box optimisation algorithms use this as underlying principle (e.g. CMA-ES). They are using MLE-estimators and reweighing the samples $X_n$ prior to fitting, depending on how good the function they optimise is in that point. However, we noticed some odd behaviour, which I distilled into this question. If this problem could be solved, perhaps with a reparametrisation of the Gaussian, there is probably a powerful unbiased black box algorithm hiding there.

Comment: The point of my comment is that is impossible.  It's important to use the history of where you've been, for otherwise you will just wander all over without converging to anything.